# Unable to ping vpn clients from target subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, openvpn, amazon-vpc

I'm using AWS vpn endpoint to connect vpn clients to a subnet:
[image: vpn info]
[image: vpn routing]
I am able to ping an ec2 instance on cidr 10.0.0.0/16 when connected using the vpn endpoint. However that ec2 instance is unable to ping clients using their client ip in the 172.16.0.0/16 cidr.

Do I have to update the routing rules on the VPC or Subnet to access the client cidr? The VPC is currently on cidr 10.0.0.0/16 and the subnet the ec2 instance is on is on subnet with cidr 10.0.64.0/24.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had opened a ticket in AWS Support and they confirmed that is working as designed: traffic will ONLY work in one direction. It is because client's IP is NAT'd. Here is AWS Support response for my ticket response:

> I understand that you have a client VPN (CVPN) set up and you were
>   able to successfully connect (initiate TCP connection) to EC2
>   instances, but the EC2 instances cannot connect to the client IP
>   assigned to the clients.
>
> As stated in the following link:
>   https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/introducing-aws-client-vpn-to-securely-access-aws-and-on-premises-resources/
>
> Note that CVPN will use source NAT (SNAT) to connect to resources in
>   the associated VPC(s).
>
> So, any traffic initiated from the client's IP will be NAT'd (source
>   IP of the client will be changed) to the IP address of the CVPN
>   endpoint. So, the EC2 instance will see as if the traffic is being
>   sourced from the CVPN endpoint IP and not from the client's IP. Also,
>   the VPC route table will not have a route to the client IP's subnet
>   (refer to VPC route table rtb-0ef010cd7b387b8ff). Hence, the
>   connection can only be initiated from the client to the EC2 instance
>   and it wouldn't work for the connections initiated in the other
>   direction.

Comment: Hey Rodrigo - does this mean that VPN traffic is from VPN clients into VPC and not the other way around? is two way traffic not possible?

Comment: @Rodrigo Pompei Did you find any alternative?

Comment: @RohitHazra Did you find the alternative you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

check the Security Groups; once you associate the first subnet with the endpoint, AWS automatically adds a default security group, which may not allow incoming ICMP traffic from the subnet where the EC2 is running.

Comment: The security group allows all traffic